# Rails 3 ActionMailer: :escape => false doesn't work, nor does raw()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, escaping, actionmailer

I want to append query string parameters to URLs generated from Rails 3 ActionMailer templates, but the ampersands are being entity escaped.

`<%= user_url(@user, :host => 'example.com', :foo => 'bar', :fubar => 'baz') %>`

results in a URL with an HTML-escaped ampersand (as expected), like

`http://example.com/user/123?foo=bar&amp;fubar=baz`

(notice it's **`&amp;`** not **`&`**)

I don't want the escaping (because it breaks the URLs).  I used to be able to add `:escape => false`, but this doesn't affect the result now.  I tried putting the query string parameters in a string like `?foo=bar&fubar=baz` and using `raw()` like

`<%= user_url(@user, :host => 'example.com') + raw("foo=bar&fubar=baz") %>`

but this also escaped my ampersand.

Is there a way to pass unescaped query string parameters in HTML email URLs?

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Comment: Tom, I have a very similar problem, except I'm using rails 2.3.12. You said, ":escape => false" helped you in rails 2, but it doesn't look like it's working for me. Sorry for questioning instead of answering, but, could you explain me how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this in the Rails tickets. It's marked as 'closed', but still appears to be a problem as of 3.1.0.rc4.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/687

EDIT: I was able to fix this by wrapping my url helper in `raw()`. E.g.

```
<%= raw( user_url(@user, :host => 'example.com', :foo => 'bar', :fubar => 'baz') ) %>
```

Comment: This is how we're dealing with it, too.  Thanks!

Comment: Another finding (a year and a half later!) -- with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8 `:escape => true` still doesn't work, and if you try to do interpolation inside the URL, it will also escape the ampersands